# creating bigquery auth. views in a different cloud project where source dataset is present using python

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

can we create a authorized bigquery view in a google cloud project A which has source data present in a different cloud project B from a python API.

i can create the above said process manually from the BQ UI, but i want to automate the process of creating around 800 auth. views from a python process.

the issue i am facing is  at a given time , i can only call a single bigquery service credentials, so whenever i trigger my process/code, i am getting the source dataset or view dataset credentials missing

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
import os

from config_files import config
from config_files import db2_table_config


os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = config.bq_service_account #service credentials of project B
client = bigquery.Client()
project = 'project_A'
source_dataset_id = 'dataset_b' # which is in different project
source_table_id = 'table'  # which is in different project
shared_dataset_ref = client.dataset('dataset_a') #target dataset for project B


view_ref = shared_dataset_ref.table("my_shared_view") #need to be created in project B
view = bigquery.Table(view_ref)
view.view_query =  "select query"

view = client.create_table(view)  # API request

print("Successfully created view at {}".format(view.full_table_id))
```

Answer (score 0):

If your use case is to “share views” with different groups with different needs. I would recommend that you review this article.[The subtle art of sharing “views” in BigQuery](https://medium.com/@mbha_phoenix/the-subtle-art-of-sharing-views-in-bigquery-7fc553cb9e77), this explains exactly what is needed to achieve your goal. Although this walk-through deals specifically with setting it up via the Console UI. I think this is a very good post for understanding the permissions required to share views across different projects for users with differing needs.

> “We share access to BigQuery tables and views using project- level IAM
>   roles or dataset-level access controls. Currently, access controls are
>   not directly applicable to tables or views.”

In order to be consistent with the principle of least privilege, you should use dataset-level access controls rather than project-level access controls. Essentially this is a question of setting the appropriate permissions.In particualr the control of access to Datasets and also views

As per the official documentation you cannot share access to tables or views directly.in particular you [control the access to datasets](http://Controlling%20access%20to%20datasets), also [the access to views](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/view-access-controls)

Your particular case might be best served by the use of Custom roles.These enable you to enforce the principle of least privilege, making certain that user/service accounts have only the minimum permissions needed to performing their tasks. [Understanding IAM custom roles](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-custom-roles), [Understanding IAM custom roles](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-custom-roles)

As for the implementation using the Python Client library. I would advise reviewing the listed documentation all of which contains code snippets in Python showing how each of the steps are implemented in code.

Further Reading:

[Introduction to views](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/views-intro)

[Creating Views](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/views)

[Getting view information](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/view-metadata)

[Creating authorized views](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/authorized-views)

[Updating Views](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/updating-views)

[Managing Views](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-views)

[Predefined roles and permissions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control#roles)

Comment: hey@paddy , thanks for the info, but i am really looking if i can programatically create a auth view in a project A and the source dataset is in different project B.

can we do it via process(python) rather than manually

Comment: hi... yes you can but what  you want to do is a bit involved which is why I  used the first doc as kind of proof of concept.. To implement this you would really need to review the posted documents... all of which have code snippets showing how to achieve the individual steps required. Combining it all together to have a deployable code base for creating and sharing views programmatically is unfortunately beyond the scope of Google Support. We are very limited in code review and direct recommendations, or writing code for users of the platform mostly for legal reasons.

Comment: But all the info you need to achieve your aim is contained above